# What is the chance of having a 10 of one suit and all other cards of other suits?

Tags: probability

A game consists of 32 cards (A, K, Q, J, 10, 9, 8, 7) in four suits, and each player gets 8 cards.

I need to find the probability that I am being dealt a 10 of one suit, and have all my other cards be of a different suit. I know the chance of having a 10 is 1/8, but I get stuck on this.

The card game is a Dutch card game called 'klaverjassen'. There are 4 suits, just like a normal card game. Each player gets 8 cards out of the 32 cards. Now I need the probability that I get a 10 of one suit, and all of my 7 other cards of different suits. For example if my 10 is a diamond, the other 7 cards either need to be clubs, spades or hearts. It doesn't matter which one it is. So I have 24 cards left where I need to pick 7 cards out of.

There are 4 10's in the game. The goal I have is that I have at least 1 10 in my hand, with all other 7 cards being of a different suit than that 10. I can have multiple 10's, as long as one of them is 'unique', meaning that the other  7 cards are not of the 10's suit. So I can have a 10 of hearts, 10 of clubs, 10 of spades and 10 of diamonds in my hand and when all other cards are also hearts, it is still good

Comment: This isn't clear.  I assume there are four suits, each with these $8$ ranks?  Do the other $7$ cards have to have the same suit?

Comment: Note:  the chance of having a $10$ in eight cards is not $\frac 18$.  It's $1-\binom {28}8/\binom {32}8\approx 0.705$.

Comment: You could add that this is the popular card game 29.

Comment: The card game is a Dutch card game called 'klaverjassen'. There are 4 suits, just like a normal card game. Each player gets 8 cards out of the 32 cards. Now I need the probability that I get a 10 of one suit, and all of my 7 other cards of different suits. For example if my 10 is a diamond, the other 7 cards either need to be clubs, spades or hearts. It doesn't matter which one it is. So I have 24 cards left where I need to pick 7 cards out of.

Comment: @LeonvandenBoogaard Please edit your question to include this information rather than placing this information in a comment, where it might be missed.

Comment: Still don't think it's clear.  What if there are multiple $10's$ or is this excluded?

Comment: @lulu I was about to ask the same question.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  Great minds think alike (whereas fools never differ.  Proverbs aren't all that helpful, really).

Comment: Specific question:  would the hand $\{10\spadesuit, 10\heartsuit, 10\diamondsuit, 10\clubsuit, A\heartsuit, K\heartsuit, Q\heartsuit, J\heartsuit\}$ be good or bad?

Comment: lulu, that would be a good hand, with only 1 spade 10, and the rest of the cards (doesn't matter if there are more 10's) being non-spades. Sorry for this unclearancy.

Comment: Multiple 10's are allowed, as long as at least one 10 is unique (all other cards are of a different color than that 10)

Comment: That's fine, but please edit your post to include all the relevant details.

Comment: I edited the original post with I think are all the neccisary details

Comment: "Heel veel geklaverjast" in younger years on high-school :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:  the final answer I arrive at seems too high to me, so I suspect that some arithmetic errors have been made.  The core methodology should be sound but the calculation should be checked carefully.

Assuming that multiple $10's$ are allowed.  We will work by the number of $10's$ in the hand.  The case where only one $10$ is allowed is Case I.

Case I:  exactly one $10$.  Then there are $4$ suits for the $10$, after which there are $21$ allowable cards in the other suits so:  $$\boxed {4\times \binom {21}7\Big/\binom {32}8\approx 0.044220074}$$

Case II:  exactly two $10's$  There are $\binom 42=6$ ways to choose the ranks, fix one choice.  Then if one of the ranks  (of the two $10's$) is to be a singleton, there are $21$ acceptable cards of the other suits so the probability that the other six cards are acceptable is $\binom {21}6/\binom {32}8\approx 0.005159009$  Similarly, the probability that both $10's$ are singletons is $\binom {14}6/\binom {32} 8\approx 0.000285502$  It follows that the answer in this case is $$\boxed {6\times \left(2 \times  0.005159009-0.000285502\right)\approx 0.060195089}$$

Case III:  exactly three $10's$  There are $\binom 43=4$ ways to choose the ranks, fix one choice.  The probability that a  specified rank is a singleton is $\binom {21}5/\binom {32}8\approx 0.001934628$.  The probability that two specified ranks are both singletons is $\binom {14}5/\binom {32}8 \approx 0.000190335$ and the probability that all three are singletons is $\binom 75/\binom {32}8\approx 1.99652E-06$.  Thus, by Inclusion Exclusion, the answer in this case is $$\boxed {4\times \left(3\times 0.001934628-3\times 0.000190335+1.99652E-06\right)\approx 0.020939505}$$

Case IV:  four $10's$.  The probability that a specified rank is a singleton is $\binom {21}3/\binom {32}8\approx 0.000126446$.  The probability that two specified ranks are both singletons is $\binom {14}3/\binom {32}8\approx 3.46064E-05$ and the probability that three are singletons is $\binom 73/\binom {32}8\approx 3.32753E-06$ whence, again by Inclusion Exclusion, the probability of this case is approximately  $$\boxed {0.000311457}$$

The final answer is then, barring arithmetic error (highly probable!):  $$.044220074+.060195089+.020939505+000311457= \boxed{ 0.125666125}$$

Note:  this seems too high to me, so I would strongly recommend checking the steps carefully.

Comment: I got about $0.127$ (as with you, via a method I'm not entirely confident in), so I suspect the answer is somewhere in that vicinity.

Comment: @BrianTung  Thanks.  I can't see anything conceptually wrong with it, but my intuition is unhappy.  I suppose I ought to just simulate it.

Comment: For comparison's sake, my expression was $[4C(24, 7)-6C(16, 6)+4C(8, 5)]/C(32, 8)$.

Comment: The way you answer is correct I think, but the answer @BrianTung had, was correct in the program I had to enter it in. Thank you all very much!!!

Comment: @BrianTung I found $0,1271$ as answer, via a method that is trustworthy.

Comment: Yes...there must be a (small) arithmetic error in what I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ denote the event of getting the $10$ of spades and no other
spades.

Let $D$ denote the event of getting the $10$ of diamonds and no
other diamonds.

Let $C$ denote the event of getting the $10$ of clubs and no other
clubs.

Let $H$ denote the event of getting the $10$ of hearts and no other
hearts.

With inclusion/exclusion and symmetry we find:

$$\begin{aligned}\mathsf P\left(S\cup D\cup C\cup H\right) & =\binom{4}{1}\mathsf P\left(S\right)-\binom{4}{2}\mathsf P\left(S\cap D\right)+\binom{4}{3}\mathsf P\left(S\cap D\cap C\right)\\
 & =\binom{32}{8}^{-1}\left[4\cdot\binom{24}{7}-6\cdot\binom{16}{6}+4\cdot\binom{8}{5}\right]\\
 & =\frac{1336592}{10518300}\\
 & \simeq0,127073006
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: This is exactly the way I reasoned to the answer, and it is exactly the value I obtained.  It seems conceptually simpler to me than the other way, but they should both be valid in principle.  lulu must be overcounting or undercounting something minor somewhere.